# PYTHON WebServer Daemon

Tags: python, http, server, cgi

The following code is a WebServer written by me.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import BaseHTTPServer
import CGIHTTPServer


server = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
handler = CGIHTTPServer.CGIHTTPRequestHandler
server_address = ("", 80)
handler.cgi_dicrectories = ["/cgi"]


httpd = server(server_address, handler)

try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
        httpd.shutdown()
```

The problem is that every time I use it, I have to launch it.
How can I make it become a Demon and make it work in the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cat use [RunIt](http://smarden.org/runit/) or write daemon on python (see a [python-daemon](https://github.com/serverdensity/python-daemon))

Answer (score 0):

Try the next one:

```
gunicorn -D -b 127.0.0.1:80 -w 9 -c file_name.py customapp:application
```

Or configure it on your own with http://gunicorn.org manual